# "Was never hard the score to guess"

Tags: lyrics

Now I'm trying to write songs and from time to time comes the moment when I always regret myself about why I didn't continued with proper learning.

Here´s my question:

> Since we met each other
> **Was never hard the score to guess**
> You were my #1 crush
> And it seems i was your perfect catch

(can it be possible this way of writing? or has to be "was never hard to guess the score")

Comment: What song is this from.  There is a general warning about "lyrics".  They frequently don't match the way English is normally spoken or written, but the words are ordered to make them sound better when sung.

Comment: @JamesK The lyrics are the OP's.....[rewrite: Since we found each other, The score was never hard to guess, You were my greatest crush and I your perfect  catch.] Your second line simply does not work as written, even as a lyric.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this sentence is eloquently written mostly for poetry or lyric of a song. To make it look normal one can rearrange the words, as follows:

> To guess the score was never hard.